# using struct variable from .h file in .c

Tags: c

shm_fileuploader.c:

```
#include "sharedMemory.h"

struct filesharing_struct temp()
{
  printf("Enter the name of the file. ");
  scanf("%s", &fname);
}
```

sharedMemory.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>


//void* get();

const int SIZE = 40960;
const char *name = "obaloch_filesharing";

struct filesharing_struct{
  char flag;
  int size;
  char content;
  char fname[50];
};

//struct filesharing_struct temp;
```

I am getting an error saying "error: ‘fname’ undeclared" and im not sure why since fname is declared in my header file. Is there anyway i can use fname in the from the .h file in the .c file?

Comment: There is no `fname` variable. It's a field inside a struct. You need to declare a variable of that struct  type and acacess the `fname` field. For example: `struct filesharing_struct s; scanf("%s", s.fname);`

Comment: This is totally unrelated to using header files. You would get the same error in one single file. You need to study the basics of C.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable whose type is the structure, and scan into its `fname` member.

Then you can return the structure from the function, to satisfy the return type.

```
struct filesharing_struct temp()
{
    struct filesharing_struct temp;

    printf("Enter the name of the file. ");
    scanf("%s", &temp.fname);
    return temp;
}
```